# Importing Tensorflow in Matlab via Python interface

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow

I am trying to use a Python script which uses Keras/Tensorflow as part of a larger Matlab project. Matlab can run Python modules just fine. Running the Python scripts directly from the terminal works fine. But combining the two fails in an interesting way:

The Matlab:

```
% tensorflowTest.m
mod = py.importlib.import_module('tensorf');
py.importlib.reload(mod);
```

The Python:

```
# tensorf.py
import tensorflow
```

The result:

```
Error using pywrap_tensorflow><module> (line 52)
Python Error: ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cfedk/shared/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/cfedk/shared/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/cfedk/shared/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/cfedk/shared/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/cfedk/shared/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Error in __init__><module> (line 49)
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

Error in __init__><module> (line 24)
from tensorflow.python import *

Error in tensorf><module> (line 1)
import tensorflow

Error in <frozen importlib>_call_with_frames_removed (line 222)

Error in <frozen importlib>exec_module (line 678)

Error in <frozen importlib>_load_unlocked (line 673)

Error in <frozen importlib>_find_and_load_unlocked (line 958)

Error in <frozen importlib>_find_and_load (line 969)

Error in <frozen importlib>_gcd_import (line 986)

Error in __init__>import_module (line 126)
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

Which is interesting because `ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` is something that we see before installing libcuddn or if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set correctly.

This also happens if importing tensorflow directly: `py.importlib.import_module('tensorflow');`

I would prefer having to resort to an RPC/separate process for this. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you google for generic python-on-MATLAB envvar/path shenanigans? Might be a more general issue.

Comment: Looks like matlab resets LD_LIBRARY_PATH to it's own stuff - overwriting rather than appending to whatever is set in bashrc. Unfortunately adding cuda's lib folder either through setenv or in python via os.environ doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Problem was starting Matlab from a launcher. Starting from bash works. Obvious mistake.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it! I suggest that you look around on SO (probably with googling with "site:stackoverflow.com" because the internal search engine is somewhat suboptimal), and if there's no similar post and you think it can help future readers, answer your own question. Either that or delete it, which you can do without any repercussions as long as there are no answers or downvotes on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting Matlab from a terminal or setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the launcher solves this.